# delete mysql_array_fetch

Tags: mysql, arrays, fetch

I have the following code and the plan is to display the data from the database but allow for the administrator of the site to delete a row if a job is no longer available. I have put "Delete" where I would like a link to delete the row.I have tried using `<a href='delete1.php?del=$row[JobID]'>Delete</a>` but that just throws an error up on the page.

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Job ORDER BY JobID");

echo "<table border='1'>
      <tr>
          <th>Job ID</th>
          <th>Job Title</th>
          <th>Job Description</th>
          <th>Industry</th>
          <th>Job Type</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
          <th>County</th>
          <th>Town</th>
          <th>Delete</th>
     </tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['JobID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['JobTitle'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['JobDescription'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Industry'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['JobType'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Salary'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['County'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Town'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "Delete" . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: shouldnt it be `<a href="delete1.php?del=$row[\'JobID\']">Delete</a>`

Comment: @JohnConde Those look like `mysqli_` functions to me. The title is misleading.

Comment: 1) What error? 2) How does `delete1.php` look like?

Comment: provide the code of delete.php

Comment: @dreamweiver why would you escape the ' symbols inside the " string?

Comment: @Goodwine no need to, because it is also wrong. To put complex variables in a double quoted string, you use curly braces: `"hello {$row['world']}"`.

Comment: @Goodwine: sorry my mistake,its not required when enclosed within "(double quotes).In question,user had used single quotes for specifying the values within href ,so i escaped it.

Answer (score 1):

You should put this in the the listing code:

```
 echo "<a href='delete1.php?del={$row['JobID']}'>Delete</a>";
```

([documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex))

Then, in your `delete1.php` you should have something like:

```
$jobid = intval($_GET['JobID']);
if ($jobid > 0) {
     mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM Job WHERE JobID=$jobid LIMIT 1");
}
```

(note: this is untested and can be quite insecure; it only shows the concept on how to do this)